# Show keyboard on Show of Modal Ionic - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a modal view containing a textarea and when the modal is show I want the keyboard to appear. Here is my code

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/inputtextarea.html', {
              scope: $scope,
              animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.show().then(document.getElementById("textarea").focus());
            document.getElementById("textarea").maxLength = 256;
        });
```

The keyboard is shown the first time the modal is shown, but when I close the modal and then show it again to update the text in the textarea, the keyboard is not show? Why does is show the first time but not the second, third, ect... and how can I get it to be shown each time the modal is shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the modal on modal close function. This also means that you will have to call and create the modal each time you call the modal open function

```
$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
    $scope.modal.remove();
};
```